# How to extract a link using xpath

Tags: c#, xpath

I'm trying to make an application where you input a web url (`http://www.explosm.net/comics/3104/`) and it automatically saves a string with the first link it finds given the xpath (`//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/img`), which is a picture I want to download.

I honestly have no clue where to even begin with this. I've tried the `HtmlAgilityPack` and the `WebBrowser` class, but I couldn't find anything to help me understand what to do and how to do it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: htmlagilitypack should work fine. What is your problem with htmlagilitypack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty easy with *HTMLAgilityPack*.

```
var w = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = w.Load("http://www.explosm.net/comics/3104/");

var imgNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"maincontent\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/img");

var src = imgNode.GetAttributeValue("src", "");
```

The variable `src` will have the value `http://www.explosm.net/db/files/Comics/Matt/Dont-be-a-dickhead.png`.

All you have to do then is download the image:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(src);
var response = request.GetResponse();

var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

//Here you have an Image object
Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);

//And you can save it or do whatever you want
img.Save(@"C:\file.png");
```

Comment: Wow. That looks incredibly simple. Thank you very much for that. :)
Quick question about HTMLAgilityPack, though. I downloaded the 1.4.6 version and there's lost of different subfolders in there. Which one should I use? (net20, net40, net40-client, net45, sl3, etc)

Comment: depending on the version of the framework you're using in your project.

Comment: Ohhh ok. I'm using version 4 and the code you gave me is perfect. Thank you very much for your help. :)